# Iphone App Similar to the Talking Larry Application

Tags: iphone

I am developing iphone application similar to the Talking Larry Application. I am facing an issue of Low Memory when i pre-load the animations into an NSMutable Array. If i do not pre-load the animations and load it into the Animation Images when the user touch the button then it takes Time and it play back the animation very Slow. And during video making it does not play the complete animations. How can i resolve this issue. I want to play back the animations similar to the Talking Larry app and do not want to get Low Memory Issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to “juggle” the images, freeing those that are not needed and preload those that will be needed soon. The trick is probably preloading a decent number of images beforehand, so that the animation does not slow down when started. You have to experiment to get the right numbers.

And of course, it also depends on the image resolution. I don’t know Talking Larry, but if you are trying to animate full-resolution retina images, it might be too much for the machine.